# Segue not updating delegate window

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwindow

I have a controller that chooses one of 2 segues and executes them immediately at `viewDidAppear:`. One of them leads to a UINavigationController and the other leads to a UITabBarController and both of them implement `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

At some point the user can open a overlay controller that will check for the presented view controller and replicate the `preferredStatusBarStyle`

My problem is that I can never get the current view controller being displayed. I'm using the code bellow to get the current controller but it is always returning the first controller ever showed (the storyboard root view controller) and not the current one.

```
internal override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
  if let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController {
    return rootViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle()
  } else {
    return .Default
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It returns the first viewController because you get rootViewController of the window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController

Comment: Isn't the old view controller replaced? docs: `If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed.`

Comment: That just means that the views are removed and not rendered anymore, but the viewController hierarchy stays the same if you don't replace root view controller. As I understand, you just present view controller. So, the root view controller stays on the bottom.

Comment: So how do I get the last displayed controller?

Comment: If you will never need that root view controller, you can just replace the root viewController instead of presenting new.
Also you can take 'presentedViewController' of a rootViewController, I guess it will be the controller you need